# Laravel 5.2 Auth always redirect to login page (maybe session not persisting)

Tags: php, laravel, session, authentication, laravel-5

Edit: Problem "solved", I downgraded to 5.1.

I meet a problem with Laravel 5.2 since a moment:

- Laravel's sessions (_token) work but mine not,
- Auth always redirect to login page.

I looked for a solution on the Internet and I tried several but none works.

Here is my code:

adminController@login:

```
$userdata = array(
    'username' => $request->get('username'),
    'password' => $request->get('password'),
);

if(Auth::validate($userdata))
{
    if(Auth::attempt($userdata)) {
        return redirect()->intended('admin-dashboard');
    }else{
        return redirect('admin-login')->with('error', 'Nom d\'utilisateur ou mot de passe incorrect !');
    }
}else{
    return redirect('admin-login')->with('error', 'Nom d\'utilisateur ou mot de passe incorrect !');
}
```

Routes.php:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {

    Route::post('postAdminLogin', ['as' => 'postAdminLogin', 'uses' => 'adminController@login']);

    Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
        Route::get('admin-dashboard', ['as' => 'admindashboard', 'uses' => 'adminController@index']);
    });

});
```

MiddlewareGroups:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,

        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,

        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,

        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,

        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,

    ],

    'auth' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
    ],
];
```

adminController@index:

```
public function index(){
  if (Auth::check()) {
    return "ok";
  }
}
```

I would be grateful if one of you could help me.

Comment: Try to replace $request->get() with $request->input()? Do you receive any validator error?

Comment: It amounts to the same thing apparently. I have no error (debug = true), If I remove my route '"admin-dashboard" and puts it outside the "auth" group, I am correctly redirected but sessions don't work.

Comment: Did you try clearing your cookies if you went from 5.1 to 5.2? I often have session or auth issues when cookies are used from another testing site (say I use localhost:8000 for 5 sites, switching on/off, the problem seems to occur)

Comment: The project is accommodated and separated from the others and I began it in 5.2. (PS: No problem with 5.1)

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem where my permissions weren't set correctly for `storate/framework/sessions/` (i.e. the application wasn't able to create the session file).

A general workaround for anyone that has similar issues could be changing your driver to `database`. The `artisan` automatically creates `sessions` schema when you run `php artisan make:auth` anyway.

Simply change `config/session.php`

```
'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'driver'),
```